# AWS Load balancer drops out query params

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have a springboot REST API which accepts search params via query, like:

http://www.example.org/myrepo?page-number=1&page-size=2

When run locally, our API receives entire URL: http://www.example.org/myrepo?page-number=1&page-size=2

But when we deploy on aws ECS Fargate -> behind an application load balancer -> the query params are clipped off by the time request reaches api.

So api access logs receive: http://www.example.org/myrepo

We think its aws ALB that is causing the issue. Does anyone have experience? Any pointers are appreciated.

We tried to search, but the closest related thread we got was this:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=796333&#796333

where someone had similar issue with S3 redirects.

Comment: Have you setup any custom routing rules in the ALB? If so, I suggest including those in the question.

Comment: just found out it was an issue with API Gateway not ELB. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JavaTec - I'm experiencing the same issue. Can you share what you found with your API gateway?